# require_once() Permisson Denied even after chmod 777

Tags: php, ubuntu, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I do Dropbox-API

it needs to access the Dropbox-SDK..

Here is the error shown in browser.

> Warning:  require_once(dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/albert/public_html/test/search.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/albert/public_html/test/search.php on line 11

I have been researching about it and try to chmod all the files, also chown all.. but it still show the same error..

Can anyone help? Thx

Comment: are you sure that autoload.php file has 777 permission ? did you change the permission using chmod -R ?

Comment: Yes.. I am sure about it..

Comment: Whatever it is that you are doing, `chmod 777` is the wrong thing to do. You should revert this change ASAP, or in the worst case reinstall your system. Think about it; you are granting the whole world unrestricted **write** access to code you are going to be executing!?

Comment: Thx for your advise.. i will gladly change it to 755.. Thx..

Answer (score 2):

Check your [include path](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php) for it may be that you have to change it or [include/require](http://www.php.net/manual/function.include.php) the autoload file using its full path.

Comment: I have tried to do so.. but unfortunately it still show the similar errors.. Thx

Comment: What is the full path to the sdk files?

Comment: /home/albert/public_html/test/dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php

Comment: Since the error is "permission denied", what is the permission on those files and directories, and also the owner of the sdk files and test file?

Comment: The permission is 777 for all files and folder.. I am sure of it.. and about the owner.. i already do `chown nobody` to all..

Comment: How is that "search.php" called? From console or from web server?

Comment: i just call it from browser local server.. localhost/albert/test/search.php

Answer (score 1):

Is dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php under `.` or `/usr/share/php` or `/usr/share/pear`, if not, that is your problem - your include path is incorrect, or your installation path for Dropbox was placed in the wrong place

Comment: Its under . I am sure i don't write the wrong path.. Because if i do, the error will be file not found..

Comment: Is the path /home/albert/public_html/test/dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/ allows to execute code? i.e. does Apache allows this path to run PHP code?

Comment: yes, its path allows execute code, but i dont know the rest.. How to check if Apache allows this path to run PHP or not? thx

Comment: Just access the path from the browser, something like http://yoursite/~albert/test/dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/somephpfile.php should not return any error of execution

Comment: it says 403 forbidden, `You don't have permission to access /albert/test/dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/Client.php on this server.
Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80` What should i do?

Comment: Allow access, are you the admin if the web server? if not, you need to contact him